# Block view, but allow sunlight from windows

Tags: windows

I live in a rental property where some of the rooms (living room, and bedroom) are situated right next to the street.

I would like to block the view from the street so people looking in can't easily see the insides of my apartment - it's ok if people looking into the room from the street you can see the outline/shadow of people who are inside. I have some pull-down blinds (similar to http://made2style.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/dsc_03271.jpg) which can block the view but these also prevent the sunlight from coming into the rooms. Ideally I could block the view but allow some sunlight to still pass through.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this? As I am just renting I'm looking for a simple solution - perhaps some kind of screen which I can temporarily prop up against the window?

Comment: What kind of blinds do you have, and did you try adjusting them so the slats point up towards the sun?

Comment: Venetian or 1" mini blinds seems like what you need, that's what BMitch is referring to.

Comment: I currently have pull-down blinds on the windows rather than venetian blinds (just edited question to reflect this).

Comment: Sheer curtains are the traditional solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static-cling (clean window, apply with water and a supplied squeegee, no actual adhesive, peels off when you leave without a fight) "stained glass" plastic films are available. They look pretty much as good or bad as you make them look, which is mostly a matter of how carefully you cut the edges. I did a bathroom over with them this spring, and it's a huge improvement over the blinds it used to have. The particular version/brand I used was "ArtScape" and it was found most affordably via Amazon, though HD does carry some of the patterns, but at a higher price.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [cellular shades](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Snow-Drift-Cordless-Cellular-Shade-48-in-Length-Price-Varies-by-Size-10793478630233/202587002)?

[image: cellular shade]

They are fairly cheap, easy to install, admit a good amount of light and obscure the view.

They are also available with a *top down* feature (for extra money) that allows you to lower the top portion to allow in light but block the view from a parallel point.

```
 Links and images are for illustration only and not an endorsement.
```

Comment: bib - obviously just trying to sell some blinds on the side.

Comment: @DMoore If I got a nickel for every product I linked or illustrated, I could buy this site! (And think how rich Tester101 would be!!)